# start-all.sh giving error of not resolving hostname and name or servce not known

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

i am setting up hadoop-2.7.2 on ubuntu 14.04 through VMware.

After steps described in michael g. noll's tutorials , when i tried this,

```
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
```

i am getting this stuff,

```
Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh

16/07/22 04:16:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Starting namenodes on [OpenJDK Client VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.

It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
localhost]

sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'

now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known

localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu.out

have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known

might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known

library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known

which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known

loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known

VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname vm: Name or service not known

try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known

stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known

have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known

You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known

The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known

to: ssh: Could not resolve hostname to: Name or service not known

Client: ssh: Could not resolve hostname client: Name or service not known

disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known

OpenJDK: ssh: Could not resolve hostname openjdk: Name or service not known

will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known

fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known

VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname vm: Name or service not known


the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known

that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known

guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known

stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known

recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not 
known

you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known

highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known

library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known

link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: Name or service not known

the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known

fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known

with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known

or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known

with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known

it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known

warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known

It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it's: Name or service not known

<libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not 
known

'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not 
known

'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known


The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.

ECDSA key fingerprint is 12:89:78:95:e5:a9:e8:84:1d:6b:c5:c9:29:16:3b:f3.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? have: ssh: Could not 
resolve hostname have: Name or service not known



localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
```

It's giving the same error while i execute stop-all.sh

i have tried fixing it by installing execstack and running command

```
execstack -c /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/lib-hadoop.so.1.0.
```

It's giving the same message with this content ,

```
localhost: namenode running as process 6003. Stop it first.

'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known

It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it's: Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known

'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known

<libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not known

localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu.out

Starting secondary namenodes [OpenJDK Client VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.

It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
0.0.0.0]
```

Apart from this, i can connect to my namenode web UI but i can't make it to Jobtracker and Tasktracker ones.

This can be some linux error. 
 Don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Your script has Windows line endings. Run `dos2unix` on it.

Answer (score -1):

edit hosts file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

see that your device name matches the one in hosts file

example kingpc is device name that matches the name in hosts file